# MonthCalendar in C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, monthcalendar

i have database from which i get data to my C# app using SQL query.

I have option in my app which get data for current day selected from MonthCalendar:

```
"between '" + monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Month.ToString() + "' and '" + monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.AddDays(1).ToString()+
```

so when i select 2012-03-06 from my calendar form i get something like this for my sql query:

```
between '2012-03-06' and '2012-03-12'
```

And it's working.

Now i'd like to get data for entire month - how to modify part of sql query so when i select day in April  i get this:

```
between '2012-04-01' and '2012-04-30'
```

?

EDIT: 
I make some progress - I have first day of month, but how to get last?

```
monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Year.ToString()+"-"+monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0')+"-"+"01"
```

Comment: Please use parameterized sql-strings.

Comment: Please also edit your tags - your question has nothing to do with `MonthCalendar`, but is rather about date/time arithmetics and SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* put your SQL statements together as strings! [Remember Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) tables...

Apart from that:

```
DateTime someDay = ...;
DateTime firstOfMonth = new DateTime(someDay.Year, someDay.Month, 1);
DateTime lastOfMonth = firstOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

string sqlString = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... AND ... BETWEEN @d1 AND @d2";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", firstOfMonth);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", lastOfMonth);
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**
Come to think of it: You'll actually notice that what you want will not return any entries that are between `lastOfMonth 00:00:01` and `lastOfMonth 23:59:59`. Actually, you should query from the first of the selected month to the first of the following month to get the desired information (subtracting one Millisecond instead of one Day won't help, as SQL Server can not store milliseconds extactly).

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1);
DateTime enddate = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month));


between '" + startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and '" + enddate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+
```

use this to get last day of the selected month

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month);
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvcs/thread/218260ec-b610-4fa6-9d1b-f56f3438b721

Comment: Could you please modify your sample? Doesn't work for me in Germany. Or you might just use parameterized queries...

Comment: I was actually after the fact that you're even promoting this "concatenate strings for SQL queries" nonsense...

Comment: Question is how to get the time span for the whole month, how he can get the 1st and last day. not the SQL query problem

Comment: I know - but I consider it every developer's responsibility to tell others to prevent SQL injections when they see it. I didn't say that your date/time calculation is wrong, but when you're saying the question is only about getting a one month timespan, why do you insert the SQL code in your reply?

Comment: If u can read the question this type of statement is also included in the question and he say that it works

Answer (score -1):

```
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("03.04.2012");

    DateTime firstofMonth = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1);

    DateTime endOfMonth = firstofMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: But when i select 2012-03-20 then it adds one month to it and sub 1 day.